# What should I install in order to use Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Based on the
http://framework.zend.com/download/latest

Zend Framework + Zend Server Community Edition(CE)
Zend Framework Full Package
Zend Framework 1.10.7 Full

Should I install Zend Server Commuity Edition or just install package?

Thank you

Comment: Zend != Zend Framework; Title, tags updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends on what you want to do. Do you need a server? Then why not try Zend Server. Do you already have one set up? Then don't. The Zend Framework does not require any additional packages or specific server software: It will work on any run-off-the-mill Apache/mySQL/PHP setup.

Comment: Hello Pekka,

I am using WAMP now. After I finish the prototype, I will upload my application to a web hosting company.

Here is the question:

Q1>
It is good enough, for now, I just need the Zend Framework 1.10.7 Full. 

Q2> Then, who has to install Zend Server Community Edition?
Do I have to request the hosting company to install the Zend Server Community Edition in order to make my application work?

thank you

Comment: @q0987 in that case, I would not use Zend Server at all but install the PHP version the web hosting company uses locally, and download only the Zend Framework.

Comment: I agree with Pekka. Ideally, you should develop on the same platform as the release platform. You could even develop remotely, you don't need to install anything locally. Just upload the Zend Framework library to the application folder in the web root and configure.

Comment: Hello Pekka and Marcus,

I am totally new to Zend Framework. Thank you for your comments.

Based on both of your suggestions, I understand

1> I don't have to install the Zend Community Server on my location machine because I have installed WAMP.

2> I DO have to install and configure Zend Library so that it works with WAMP local server

3> I Do have to install and confgure Zend Library so that it works on the hosting company server.

Am I correct here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

only Zend Framework, u have just to create a zend project, with folder stucture

Comment: Hello Fincha,

what is the difference between Zend Framework Full Package and Zend Framework 1.10.7 Full?

thank you

Comment: Zend Framework Full Package contains aditional packages like zendx. demo Project, and Documentation For an usual application u just need the Zend Framework 1.10 minimal